# Google calendar API not recieveng conformaton response

Tags: java, rest, google-api, google-calendar-api

We have done the integration of Google calendar API in java, we are able to send meeting requests and attendee receives the request. However, there some issues with response when attendee click on 'yes' or 'no' button in mail, organizer will not get response.

The issue is when attendees try to accept or reject the meeting a organizer is not getting response.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have not set up the push [notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) on the event then you will be informed of changes and can notify the organizer.

You need to look for the [status on the event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) then notify the organizer I don't think this is something that Calendar is going to do for you.

```
status  string  Status of the event. Optional. Possible values are:
"confirmed" - The event is confirmed. This is the default status.
"tentative" - The event is tentatively confirmed.
"cancelled" - The event is cancelled.
```

Comment: Is this required to get notification in gmail inbox  when attendee confirm event request ?